# Set OOB theme to a Modern SharePoint Online Site

Tags: theme, modern-experience, modern-team-site, spo

In our new Modern Sites we can change the themes easily from a list of default ones. As shown below.

[image]

Now as per my assumptions the names of these default themes are Red, Blue, Orange etc.

I am provisioning new Modern Sites using PnP code. I have seen many articles mentioning easy to create a custom theme and set them. (*PS cmd: Set-PnPWebTheme OR c#: Tenant.SetWebTheme*)

But how can we set one of the default ones? Like while provisioning a modern site I want to set "Red" as a default theme for my site collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to set the default themes using Powershell.

What you can do, is copy the default theme, add it as a custom one and apply the copied/custom theme.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to this, but if you are using `PnP CSOM`, you can do this as below:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl))
{
    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Default;
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, securePassword);

    ThemeManager.ApplyTheme(clientContext.Web, OfficeDevPnP.Core.Enums.SharePointTheme.Orange);
}
```

Also, if you are using the PnP Provisioning engine, you can use the below template XML and the use the PnP commandlet , `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pnp:Provisioning xmlns:pnp="http://schemas.dev.office.com/PnP/2019/03/ProvisioningSchema">
  <pnp:Preferences Generator="OfficeDevPnP.Core, Version=3.9.1905.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
  <pnp:Templates ID="CONTAINER-TEMPLATE-189597059C6B4C3FB113CE057D982E8E">
    <pnp:ProvisioningTemplate ID="TEMPLATE-189597059C6B4C3FB113CE057D982E8E" Version="1" BaseSiteTemplate="SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0" Scope="RootSite">
      <pnp:Theme Name="Orange" IsInverted="false" />
    </pnp:ProvisioningTemplate>
  </pnp:Templates>
</pnp:Provisioning>
```

This capability was added couple of months back, so just ensure that you are using PnP CSOM and PnP PowerShell after May 2019 onwards (i.e `v 3.9.x.x and above`).

The necessary OOTB theme names are available in the enum:

[image]